# .net working with list stored in one column give me error

Tags: json, .net, linq, entity-framework-core, ef-core-8.0

I have Cards in databse, in cards table:

```cs
List<CardItem> Items
```

in CardItem:

```cs
List<CardItemContent> ContentItems
```

in CardItemContent:

```cs
string ItemKey
```

in the database configuration, I have:

```cs
builder.ToTable(
    "Cards"
);

builder.Property(e => e.Items)
    .HasConversion(
        o =>
            JsonConvert
            .SerializeObject(
            o,
            new JsonSerializerSettings()
            ),
        o =>
            JsonConvert
            .DeserializeObject<List<CardItem>>(
            o,
            new JsonSerializerSettings()
            )!
    )
```

This will store the list as json in database in one column

now I tried the following code:

```cs
var query =
    from card in dbContext.Cards
    where
    card.Items
        .Exists(
            c => c.ContentItems.Exists(ci => ci.ItemKey != null)
        )
    select card;
```

I got error:

> The LINQ expression 'c => c.ContentItems.Exists(ci => ci.ItemKey != null)' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'

Comment: Can you show more code around? Conversion for wich property? Full exception message. Which EF Core version?

Comment: I have updated the question. I'm using .net 8

Comment: EF cannot generate SQL using property which `HasConversion`, it is just impossible (except rare cases). Make `CardItem` as another table.